# Procedure in Python

Tags: python

Question

Write a procedure that takes a string of words separated by spaces (assume no punctuation or capitalization), together with a ”target” word, and shows the position of the target word in the string of words. For example, if the string is:

```
   'we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont'
```

and the target is the word ”dont” then your procedure should return the list 1, 6, 13 because ”dont” appears at the 1st, 6th, and 13th position in the string. (We start counting positions of words in the string from 0.) Your procedure should return False if the target word doesn’t appear in the string.

My solution-

```
def procedure(string,target):
    words=string.split(" ") #turn the string into a list of words
    solution=[] #list that will be displayed
        for i in range(len(words)):
            if words[i]==target: solution.append(i)
    if len(solution)==0: return False
    return solution

string="we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont"
print procedure(string, "dont")
assert procedure(string, "dont")
```

Why is this not running in python?! The problem is on `print procedure(string, "dont")` it mentions invalid syntax. I am running it in the IDLE.

Comment: Fix your indentation

Comment: Done that. The problem is on print procedure(string, "dont") it mentions invalid syntax

Comment: No, your function code block is not indented and neither is your for loop block

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not understanding it. Can you please show it to me.

Comment: In python, indentation is significant. If your code is not indented properly, it will not run.  And without proper indentation, we can't tell what it is doing.

Comment: I am very new to python - so I am having a tough time understanding such things.

Comment: @learncode When asking a question about a bug, always make sure to include any error information that you get. This helps narrow down the source of the problem. Further, make sure your code sample is runnable (in this case you need to properly indent the code otherwise other people might wrongly assume how you have indented your code). Finally, with python it is always useful to mention what version you are using (python 2.x versus python 3.x).

Comment: @Dunes Thanks ! It is my second day on stack exchange, I will learn gradually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is your code with the indentation fixed, compare this with what you posted and you should see why it now works.
It is unclear to me why your original code has a problem because the indentation controls how python views the blocks of code and will fail to run if the indentation is incorrect. I suspect that your problem is that you had these lines in your code:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i]==target: solution.append(i)
    if len(solution)==0: return False
```

The above will fail and return `False` because solution length will be 0 on the first iteration if your word is not found on the first iteration, you should check the len of solution outside the scope of the for loop.

```
In [42]:

def procedure(string,target):
    words=string.split(" ") #turn the string into a list of words
    solution=[] #list that will be displayed
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i]==target: solution.append(i)
    if len(solution)==0: return False
    return solution

string="we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont"
print(procedure(string, "dont"))
assert(procedure(string, "dont"))
[1, 6, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user a list comprehension for this:

```
def list_word_indexes(word, text):
    return [index for index, text_word in enumerate(text.split())
            if text_word == word]
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is on print procedure(string, "dont") it mentions invalid syntax

This means you are using python 3, where `print` is a function and not a statement. You should add brackets around the argument(s) to `print` or make sure to use python 2.

eg.

```
print(procedure(string, "dont"))
```